# How to approach multiple operations on dynamically located file?

Tags: scripting, ant

I am trying to build the following in ant, but honestly, don't know how best to proceed:

- Get filename based on set criteria (newest by date & regex string comparison) and break filename apart (file starts with a number which I'll use to check validity).
- Get folder name in the different directory and break apart to get number
  copy file if file validating number is greater than folder number.

So far I can copy the correct file to a temp directory but I need help with comparing parts of the file name and folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
<project name="test1" basedir="." default="check_if_new_sdk_needed">

    <property file="../local.properties" />

    <target name="check_if_new_sdk_needed" depends="check_local_sdk, compute_remote_sdk_properties">
        <echo message="Need to grab SDK: ${updateNeeded}" />
        <antcall target="process_sdk" />
    </target>

    <target name="check_local_sdk" depends="local_sdk_found, local_sdk_not_found">
    </target>

    <target name="local_sdk_found" depends="compute_local_sdk_properties" if="local.sdk.found">
        <echo message="Local SDK found" />
        <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
          var localVersion = parseInt(project.getProperty('local.sdk.version.number'));
          var remoteVersion = parseInt(project.getProperty('remote.sdk.version.number'));
          project.setProperty('updateNeeded', remoteVersion > localVersion);
      ]]></script>
    </target>

    <target name="local_sdk_not_found" depends="compute_local_sdk_properties" unless="local.sdk.found">
        <property name="updateNeeded" value="true" />
        <echo message="Need to grab SDK" />
    </target>

    <target name="compute_local_sdk_properties">
        <path id="local_sdk_folder_name">
            <dirset dir="${local.sdk.dir}">
                <include name="*"/>
            </dirset>
        </path>
        <property name="local.sdk.folder.name" refid="local_sdk_folder_name"/>
        <pathconvert property="local.sdk.version.number">
            <path path="${local.sdk.folder.name}" />
            <chainedmapper>
                <flattenmapper />
                <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*?)-.*" to="\1" />
            </chainedmapper>
        </pathconvert>
        <condition property="local.sdk.found">
            <length string="${local.sdk.version.number}" trim="true" when="greater"
                length="0" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="compute_remote_sdk_properties">
        <echo message="renaming ${sdk_folder_name} to ${remote.sdk.file.name}"/>
        <pathconvert property="remote.sdk.version.number">
            <path path="${remote.sdk.file.name}" />
            <chainedmapper>
                <flattenmapper />
                <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*?)-.*" to="\1" />
            </chainedmapper>
        </pathconvert>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Consider using a script for complex manipulations in Ant: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html